# Is there basic authentication free with elastic search (basic) distributed version or this falls under the 30 days trial feature?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there basic authentication free with elastic search (basic) distributed version or this falls under the [30 days trial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-xpack.html) feature ?

We are working on adding elastic search as indexing solution for our application. Bit confused with licensing and [subscription](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) where they mention that distributed has some feature like Xpack for security free but also mention that it is under trail version.

**So the question is can we add basic security to elastic search and use it without any trial issue or it is trial pack ?**

Answer (score 1):

basic Elastic Security features are free since v6.8 or v7.1. No trial. From [this feature matrix](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions), here's what you get for free:

- Secure settings
- Encrypted communications
- Role-based access control
- File and native authentication
- Kibana Spaces
- Kibana feature controls
- API keys management

Your basic authentication requirement is covered by using file or native authentication (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/setting-up-authentication.html), as long as you don't have to integrate your authentication process with an identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

2 options

1. Open distro from amazon
   2.https://search-guard.com/